# how to use '%' keystroke in vim command mode for languages like Ruby

Tags: ruby, vim

With Vim, pressing the '%' key on a curly brace (in command mode) moves the cursor to the corresponding opening/closing curly brace. It is quite helpful for c files and the like. How do I get this functionality for a language like Ruby, where code blocks are delineated by do/end or whatnot?

Comment: `:help %` and follow the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's available as part of https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby

You may also find https://github.com/tpope/vim-endwise useful.